# first word of the matched string in perl

Tags: perl

I have a text file, and I would like to find the string based on their offset value using `substring` function.

My input file is like:

```
[1] Line one
[2] Line two
[3] Line three
```

My code is:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $f2 = 'Test.txt';
my ($text, $str);
  open (FH1, $f2) || die;
  $text = join '', <FH1>;
  $str  = substr($text, 16, 5);
  print $str,"\n";
```

Need to find the number which present as a first word in the matched text.

The output should look like

```
[2]--Line
```

The matched string is "Line", and the first word of the line is [2].

Comment: I am getting the offset details from another file, so the only option is to find the text using offset detail. so that, I could not use the regex.

Comment: You need to find the line at position 16 in the file? And in that line you need to find the first word? If so, read the file line-by-line, keeping track of their total length. After you have read enough characters, you'll have the line you need. Then use regex to get the right word from that line.

Answer (score 0):

For information about the substr functionr refer to it's documentation at:

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html

The general form of this function is:

```
    substr EXPR,OFFSET,LENGTH
```

As well notice that you are using substr($text,16,5), but the diamond reads a file line by line(because you used it in a scalar context, so where is 16 came from?? You must start your offsets from the beginning. For information about Perl's operators refer to perlop:

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html

Comment: Your question is blurry, what do you want to find?? What is 16?? you are taking the substring of the $text(that is a line you just red from the file, and contains one line) starting at character 16 with a length of 5. But the length of text if smaller than 16, so what do you want to find??

Comment: Yes but offset and length must be correct, they must be meaningful in the context that you are using them.

Comment: Arrived the logic to grap the first word of matched substring.